# How to check if message is in the queue already

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to check if kafka queue already has certain message?
I do not want to consume it but just check if it's already in queue. E.g. my message is a simple JSON object:

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "message"
}
```

So I want to check if message with id: 123 is already in queue so my app do not send it second time.
I have Node.js service and using kafkajs npm library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want to consume it but just check if it's already in queue

That's not possible. You need to consume the topic to check existance for any event.

You'd need to consume and write to somewhere else (Redis, MongoDB, etc), then query an index on **that** to prevent duplicates with Kafka topics.

Or otherwise, embed this logic in your downstream consumers rather than worry about what is on the topic, or not, considering the fact that records are eventually removed from the topic due to retention policies.

Answer (score 0):

May be **[ksqlDB](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.13.0-ksqldb/)** can help. It converts stream into a queryable state.

Comment: But it still needs to consume the topic and doesn't prevent duplicates

Answer (score -1):

Kafka has support for idempotence through Idempotent Producer / Exactly Once semantics. Means it ensures that messages published on Kafka topics should not be duplicated from the Producer side. For consumers.

flag: `EnableIdempotence = true`

Comment: not sure if that's what I need.. I force to send same message via JavaScript code. I just need to know if same message/body already exists in the queue

Comment: This does not prevent duplicates in the whole topic. Only prevents retrying the same event in the same producer call.